# Dynamically adding image in javascript shows error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to dynamically add label and image in my code.When I added label its working fine but when I tried to add image.its not working.

```
 for(var i=0;i<output.length;i++){
 var shopname=$("<label id="+output[i].branch_id+">"+output[i].myfavourite+"</label>");
 var shopimage=$("<img id="+output[i].image+" float="left" width="100px"/>");
 $("#id").append(shopname).append(shopimage);
 }
```

Comment: use single quote instead of double quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your quotes in `float="left"` and `width` are the issue because you use double quotes to wrap the string. You can escape them like so:

```
var shopimage=$("<img id="+output[i].image+" float=\"left\" width=\"100px\"/>");
```

Although you should be setting float in CSS, not as an attribute:

```
var shopimage=$("<img id="+output[i].image+" width=\"100px\" style=\"float:left\" />");
```

The whole code would be better working with objects instead of a HTML string:

```
var shopname = $("<label></label>")
                   .prop("id", output[i].branch_id)
                   .text(output[i].myfavourite);

var shopimage = $("<img />")
                   .prop("id", "someid")
                   .prop("src", output[i].image)
                   .css({
                       width : '100px;',
                       float: 'left'
                   });

$("#id").append(shopname).append(shopimage);
```

Comment: You aren't setting any `src` attribute of the image, so nothing will show. Try adding that.

Comment: var shopimage=$("<img id="+i+"src="+output[i].image+" float=\"left\" width="100px"/>"); still not working

Comment: You need a space before `src`. Anyway see my edit for a better way.

Comment: size of image not changing even though i gave the size for it @mrcode

Comment: @NandhiniDevi use quotes around `'margin-left'` because it contains a special character. Also you didn't include jQuery in the fiddle. Working: http://jsfiddle.net/2b6LL/1/